# Azure Sentinel and 3rd part API integration

Tags: azure, api, azure-logic-apps, azure-sentinel

Is there a way to implement some prompt or pop-up window where user can insert some input values before calling 3rd party API calls from Azure Sentinel playbooks? 3rd party API calls are integrated over Azure Logic Apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that since they are all run behind the scenes.  You can pass in data from the query to the logic app so maybe that would work?